# The SSL connection could not be established only Windows PC, macOS is OK

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows

I'm trying to request a API method using code below, and only on Windows OS I'm getting this error

> "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.' AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception."

but, while trying same code using macOS, working fine and get the correct data.

There are some config to do for run this at windows?

```
 var handler = new HttpClientHandler
 {
     ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
     SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
     ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (e, r, c, n) => true,
 };

 handler.ClientCertificates.Clear();
 handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(@"cert.pfx", "xxx"));

 var client = new HttpClient(handler);

 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

 var result = await client.GetAsync("https://some_url.com/some_method");

 var tmp = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Windows server or normal windows os

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: And what is the inner exception? And why are you setting the TLS protocol manually?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) and [How to: Configure network tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing)

Comment: Also what is the Windows and .NET verison on the server? Can you get a Wireshark trace of the Client and Server Hellos.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Pro and .NET 7, I'm debug at Visual Studio...